# CMake keeps linking to libraries under /usr/lib64 even full paths to another libraries are given

Tags: linker, cmake

I am building a package with CMake (3.0.2). This package relies on boost_python and some others.  There is an older version in /usr/lib64 and I have another newer version in my own directory /home/x/opt/boost-1.56/lib. There is an symbol link /home/x/opt/boost-1.56/lib64 to deal with the multi-arch gcc.

However, even if I set `BOOST_ROOT=/home/x/opt/boost-1.56/lib`, and in CMakeCache.txt there is

```
//Boost python library (release)
Boost_PYTHON_LIBRARY_RELEASE:FILEPATH=/home/x/opt/boost-1.56/lib/libboost_python.a
```

The generated link.txt contains such a line, instead of the full path:

```
-Wl,-Bstatic -lboost_python
```

And when `make`, it links to the one under /usr/lib64/, which is wrong.

Question:

1. How to make CMake to use the full path? As documented, only when libraries under system default folders are dealt with -Bstatic, which should not be my case.
2. Why -Wl,-Bstatic -lboost_python does not work even I have "/home/x/opt/boost-1.56/lib" in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `LIBRARY_PATH`? From my limited knowledge they should override the system default.

Information:

`gcc --print-search-dir` gives:

```
/home/x/opt/boost-1.56/lib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.9.2/
/home/x/opt/boost-1.56/lib/../lib64/
/lib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.9.2/
/lib/../lib64/
/usr/lib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.9.2/
/usr/lib/../lib64/
/home/x/opt/boost-1.56/lib/
/lib/
/usr/lib/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set(Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS ON)
```

This will allow it to ignore everything but BOOST_ROOT

Answer (score 0):

Solution (partially only):

- CMake uses -Bstatic if there it thinks that the boost libraries it chooses are in the system path, including that related to enviromental variables. Else it use the full path.
- I still cannot find why LIBRARY_PATH cannot override the system
- So to make it work, REMOVE everything in LIBRARY_PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH will do the trick: CMake will use full path in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Add this at the beginn oingf your top level CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
```

and use cmake 3.3.0 or later.

Interestingly, with cmake 3.11.1 `set(Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS ON)` did not work for me.